# "Undefined" returned at end of the function

Tags: javascript

There's "Undefined" appears at the end of the second function, i can't figure the reason.
here's my code

```
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
}

// your code goes here.  Make sure you call makeLine() in your own code.
function buildTriangle(len){
    for(var i=1;i<=len; i++){
        console.log(makeLine(i));
    }
}

// test your code by uncommenting the following line
console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

Comment: That's because this is the return value.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze how can i fix this?

Comment: return another value from this function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't explicitly return a value from a function, **it implicitly returns `undefined`**.

---

You log the return value of `buildTriangle`, which is `undefined`:

```
console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

---

[See MDN for more info.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Answer (score 1):

Timo answered the *why*. Here's *one* way to fix the code so that you return the result.

Define an array and with each iteration of the loop push the result of `makeLine` to the array. Then return the joined array.

```
function buildTriangle(len){
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=1;i<=len; i++){
    arr.push(makeLine(i))
  }
  return arr.join('');
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fx7kL1q3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove console at last line .There is no need of console will you call any function.

```
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
}

// your code goes here.  Make sure you call makeLine() in your own code.
function buildTriangle(len){
    for(var i=1;i<=len; i++){
        console.log(makeLine(i));
    }
}

// test your code by uncommenting the following line
buildTriangle(10)
```

If you want to call the function inside console.log . Then return something from  `buildTriangle` function.

```
function buildTriangle(len){
    for(var i=1;i<=len; i++){
        console.log(makeLine(i));
    }
      return 'done';
}
console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```